# JS document.getElementById is not a function if you have a form with name="document"

Tags: javascript, forms, variables

I had a strange problem with my site. Suddenly, on a page I got the JS error `document.getElementById is not a function`. The problem was that I had a form with `name="document"`.

It seems that if a form has the attribute `name` set, a variable in Javascript with the same name is set.

Where can I find the specs for this ?

Comment: tried it on chrome, couldn't reproduce the error, could you paste a plunker?

Comment: [6.3.3. Named access on the Window object](http://w3c.github.io/html/browsers.html#named-access-on-the-window-object): "_The Window interface supports named properties. The supported property names at any moment consist of the following, in tree order, ignoring later duplicates: ... the value of the name content attribute for all a, applet, area, embed, form, frameset, img, and object elements in the active document that have a non-empty name content attribute..._"

Comment: @Andreas why don't you put your comment as an answer?

Comment: @arhak Because I think this is a duplicate but I haven't found it yet. Hence I've added the relevant part of the specification until I find the duplicate or give up the search :)

Comment: @aliasav https://plnkr.co/edit/xTldg4vuLeUSxJBIZs0A?p=preview Open the browser console  to see the effect

Comment: @Andreas I tried to search but I didn't find any question related to this. Anyway, the purpose was to get link to specification ))

Comment: @Andreas if you looked already and did not find it, then post the answer and get the credit for it, until a dup appears (if there is such)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behavior is defined in section [6.3.3 Named access on the Window object](http://w3c.github.io/html/browsers.html#named-access-on-the-window-object) of the HTML 5 specification:

The child browsing context name property set consists of the [browsing context names](http://w3c.github.io/html/browsers.html#browsing-context-name) of any [child browsing context](http://w3c.github.io/html/browsers.html#child-browsing-context) of the [active document](http://w3c.github.io/html/browsers.html#active-document) whose name is not the empty string, with duplicates omitted.
The Window interface [supports named properties](https://heycam.github.io/webidl/#dfn-support-named-properties). The [supported property names](https://heycam.github.io/webidl/#dfn-supported-property-names) at any moment consist of the following, in [tree order](http://w3c.github.io/html/infrastructure.html#tree-order), ignoring later duplicates:

- the [child browsing context name property set](http://w3c.github.io/html/browsers.html#child-browsing-context-name-property-set).
- **the value of the name content attribute for all [`<a>`](http://w3c.github.io/html/textlevel-semantics.html#elementdef-a), [`<applet>`](http://w3c.github.io/html/textlevel-semantics.html#elementdef-applet), [`<area>`](http://w3c.github.io/html/textlevel-semantics.html#elementdef-area), [`<embed>`](http://w3c.github.io/html/textlevel-semantics.html#elementdef-embed), [`<form>`](http://w3c.github.io/html/textlevel-semantics.html#elementdef-form), [`<frameset>`](http://w3c.github.io/html/textlevel-semantics.html#elementdef-frameset), [`<img>`](http://w3c.github.io/html/textlevel-semantics.html#elementdef-img), and [`<object>`](http://w3c.github.io/html/textlevel-semantics.html#elementdef-object) elements in the [active document](http://w3c.github.io/html/browsers.html#active-document) that have a non-empty name content attribute**, and
- the value of the id content attribute of any [HTML element](http://w3c.github.io/html/infrastructure.html#html-element) in the [active document](http://w3c.github.io/html/browsers.html#active-document) with a non-empty id content attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're right. Document supports named properties.

@Andreas has also pointed out a resource that mentions this:http://w3c.github.io/html/browsers.html#named-access-on-the-window-object

6.3.3. Named access on the Window object: "The Window interface supports named properties. The supported property names at any moment consist of the following, in tree order, ignoring later duplicates: ... the value of the name content attribute for all a, applet, area, embed, form, frameset, img, and object elements in the active document that have a non-empty name content attribute..." – Andreas

Check this out:
https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#dom-document-forms

> The Document interface supports named properties. The supported
>   property names of a Document object document at any moment consist of
>   the following, in tree order according to the element that contributed
>   them, ignoring later duplicates, and with values from id attributes
>   coming before values from name attributes when the same element
>   contributes both:
>
> the value of the name content attribute for all applet, exposed embed,
>   form, iframe, img, and exposed object elements that have a non-empty
>   name content attribute and are in a document tree with document as
>   their root;
>
> the value of the id content attribute for all applet and exposed
>   object elements that have a non-empty id content attribute and are in
>   a document tree with document as their root; and
>
> the value of the id content attribute for all img elements that have
>   both a non-empty id content attribute and a non-empty name content
>   attribute, and are in a document tree with document as their root.
>
> To determine the value of a named property name for a Document, the
>   user agent must return the value obtained using the following steps:
>
> Let elements be the list of named elements with the name name that are
>   in a document tree with the Document as their root.
>
> There will be at least one such element, by definition.
>
> If elements has only one element, and that element is an iframe
>   element, and that iframe element's nested browsing context is not
>   null, then return the WindowProxy object of the element's nested
>   browsing context.
>
> Otherwise, if elements has only one element, return that element.
>
> Otherwise return an HTMLCollection rooted at the Document node, whose
>   filter matches only named elements with the name name.
>
> Named elements with the name name, for the purposes of the above
>   algorithm, are those that are either:
>
> applet, exposed embed, form, iframe, img, or exposed object elements
>   that have a name content attribute whose value is name, or applet or
>   exposed object elements that have an id content attribute whose value
>   is name, or img elements that have an id content attribute whose value
>   is name, and that have a non-empty name content attribute present
>   also. An embed or object element is said to be exposed if it has no
>   exposed object ancestor, and, for object elements, is additionally
>   either not showing its fallback content or has no object or embed
>   descendants.